# Is there any privacy in windows phone

Tags: apps, video, pictures, nokia-lumia-535, privacy

Is there any way out with which I can hide my stuffs like images from gallery and videos too. Sometimes it happens that one cannot share everything with everyone. So, How can I hide them without deleting them from my phone and access them whenever I want and without history.

Comment: What sort of risks are you wanting to protect yourself from? Your wife not seeing pictures of your girlfriend? Your boss not knowing you're using a company mobile for personal purposes with videos of your cats? Law enforcement agencies not seeing pictures of your friends indulging in things they shouldn't? Or something else?

Comment: :D so you have different solution for all of them?

Comment: Till now I have not faced such a problem :) Just wanna know for future help!!!

Answer (score 1):

i think there is no option for hide some objects and others not , BUT there is an App in the MS Store which is called "[App Locker](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/app-locker/9wzdncrfhzk3)" which locks whole apps and requires an password to start them. (There are more Apps, but it'll make the point)

Comment: :) No, this wil not do. Because I can't lock my gallery for this reasons! Its better to use phone lock then. Anyway thank you!